# Changing Ubuntu 17.10 windows snap color

Tags: themes, colors

I have installed the Arc-Dark theme and paper icon theme to customize my Ubuntu 17.10 experience. The theme though doesn't change my sign in screen color scheme from the purple/orange to anything, and it doesn't change the window snap color from orange. As far as I can tell these are the only things it doesn't change though. I have dconf installed but I can't find anything obvious to edit to change these orange colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this question is a month old but it is unanswered and I found how to do it in Ubuntu 17.10

There is a css file in `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/` called `ubuntu.css`

Open it in your favorite editor, with `sudo`
For example:

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css
```

scroll down to the following lines:

```
/* Tiled window previews */
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 70, 0.5);
    border: 1px solid #000000; }
```

(For me they were around line number 646)

You can change the `background-color` and `border` properties to a color of your liking.
As you can see mine are set to dark blue and black.

The following link is a great tool to find a nice color: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Colors/Color_picker_tool

After you are done, save the file and log out and back in again for the changes to take effect.

Cheers!